# How to obfuscate the function names of the unmanaged dll

Tags: c, dll, export

I want to obfuscate my dll export names. 
I have come across the same question in stack overflow in the below link, However I could not find the acceptance of solution.
[Modify dll exports (symbol table). I want to obfuscate the function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698428/modify-dll-exports-symbol-table-i-want-to-obfuscate-the-function-names)

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Compile using the c++ compiler?

Comment: You could give them obfuscated names before you compile them.

Comment: Call your functions Function1 through Function999. Use macros in a header file to give them mnemonic names.

Comment: @Raymond: +1 for solution and implementation (I wouldn't have thought of it). If you had given an answer instead of commenting, I'd have you upvoted as well - with a better impact.

Comment: @raymond, a small example will help me ray.

Comment: #define PlanBirthday Function1
#define InviteBestFriend Function2
(etc)

Now your code can say `InviteBestFriend()` and all that shows up in the DLL is `Function2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a .def file, in which you can either give exported functions other names, or just export them by ordinal. See [Exporting from a DLL Using DEF Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [.def files C/C++ DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366228/def-files-c-c-dlls).

Comment: Its sounds easy eran. In shell32.dll, I have seen such ordinals in export. I tired using ordinal numbers for 2 or 3 functions in the list,but I could find the name still in exports section.

Comment: OK, I found it. I tried it with NONAME. I mean like this  EXPORTS fun1 @1 NONAME  Fun2 @2 NONAME. this gives me the success.