# Can I change mangled C++ DLL export symbols? (Binary-compatible but Source-incompatible)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport, name-mangling

Our C++ project (still) uses the option `Treat wchar_t as Built-in: No (/Zc:wchar_t-)` from back in the days when it was compiled on VS6.

This results in `wchar_t` being just a typedef for `unsigned short` (`WORD`).

We would like to change this, so that `wchar_t` is handled as a proper built-in type -- this would greatly ease integration of (modern) libs.

Problem is, we do link to a few DLLs that we *cannot* recompile that expose their strings as `unsigned short*` and their headers use `wchar_t*`. This will result in linker errors when wchar_t is a built-in type, because obviously the export symbols are different.

Changing the headers would require adding a sort of casting layer -- I certainly don't want to add casts to all code that calls into the classes in these headers.

Is it possible to fix the DLLs so that their export symbols would "pretend" to export the built-in `wchar_t`instead of `WORD`? After all, the two types are 100% binary compatible in VC++.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't suppose you can change the *headers* to actually reflect the compiled in *type* (i.e. make a copy of the DLL's headers for your project that use what is *actually in* that DLL: `unsigned short` rather than `wchar_t`). Since you can't change the code, perhaps you should ensure the compiler doesn't assume *it* can change the declaration of that code. Just a thought.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Yeah, the problem with changing the headers is that I then cannot call the functions anymore, as I'd get a type mismatch at the call site. I'd need to add wrapper functions which do some `..._cast` to convert the parameter types, but this would quickly become messy I fear. (I'd need to add inline functions into the exported C++ class headers.)

Comment: you would generally write a wrapper class for this type of thing, ie. create `class CCastFixer` which also exposes each of the methods the dll exposes, but returns the correct type, and then within those methods, call the dll methods and cast to the correct type. and then within your code, use the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine, they are binary compatible.

The only wall you could run into is the name mangling of the exported function.  If the DLLs that you cannot change exported these functions using their decorated C++ name then you'll get a fail whale at runtime when the client cannot find the exported name.  This will happen when the programmer didn't use `extern "C"` or didn't use a .def file to rename the exports.  Otherwise easy to see with Dumpbin.exe /exports.  Fixing that is painful, you'll need to modify the DLL header to change wchar_t to WORD, a macro can do that, and write little adapter functions that take wchar_t and calls the WORD function by casting.

If these are exported C++ classes then you have a bigger problem.  You'll need to create a new import library for these DLLs.  Start with the output you get from Dumpbin.exe /exports, giving you the original names.  And create a .def file from that, using its foo = bar option to rename a symbol.  Create the import library with the lib.exe /def option.  Create a little test DLL to figure out exactly how you should rename the mangled name.

Comment: yep. C++ dlls. Export c++ classes, so obviously I have the name mangling problem.

Comment: Hans - I've though about this ... With a C++ DLL, the names found in the DLL are the ones that actually are mangled to contain the type info. Since fixing the import library doesn't change the DLL, how is this going to help? Or are the functions just called by Ordinal in the resulting code?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @HansPassant 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743268/321013) I was able to pull this off.

Full steps here for reference:

1. Generate export symbols for DLL: `dumpbin /EXPORTS ddao35u.dll`
2. replace all unsigned-short-pointer types with wchar_t: This means replacing `PAG` (for `unsigned short*`) and `PBG` (for `unsigned short const*`) with the wchar_t string-mangle `PA_W` and `PB_W`
3. Write a new def file with all symbols, where the functions with strings get replaced names. Example would be:

   ```
   LIBRARY ddao35u
   EXPORTS
     ??0CdbBSTR@@QAE@PA_W@Z=??0CdbBSTR@@QAE@PAG@Z  @1   ... replaced
                     ^^^^  =                ^^^
     ??0CdbBookmark@@QAE@ABV0@@Z  @2  ... no strings, no replacement needed
   ...
   ```
4. Generate import library from def file: `lib /DEF:ddao35u.def`
5. Reference this new `ddao35u.lib` from you wchar_t-native VS project linker options instead of the original lib file.

I'm going to dump the whole perl script function I used to do this here:

```
sub fixModuleLib {
  my $basename = shift;
  my $dllpath = shift;
  # my $basename = "ddao35u";
  print "\n\n";
  my $cmdExport = "dumpbin /EXPORTS $dllpath";
  print "Running >> $cmdExport << for export symbols ...\n";
  die "Input file $dllpath not found!" unless -f "$dllpath"; 
  my @exports  = qx/$cmdExport/;

  print "Open $basename.def for writing ...\n";
  open(my $defh, ">", "$basename.def") or die "Unable to open basename.def for writing: $!";
  print $defh "LIBRARY $basename"."\n";
  print $defh "EXPORTS"."\n";

  my @expEntries;
  my $usCount = 0;
  foreach (@exports) {
    #           1    0 00002050 ??0CdbBSTR@@QAE@PAG@Z
    my $ws = '\s+';
    my $hnum = '[ABCDEFabcfed0123456789]+';
    if (m/$ws(\d+)$ws$hnum$ws$hnum$ws(\?\S+)/) {
      my $ord = $1;
      my $mangle = $2;
      my $defline;
      # PAG = unsigned short*
      # PBG = unsigned short const*
      # at least two @ signs before parameter list (at least in our case)
      if ($mangle =~ m/(.+@.*@.*)(P[AB]G)(.*)/) { # case sensitive
        my $pre = $1;
        my $uptr = $2;
        my $post = $3;
        # print "$ord\t$pre>>>$uptr<<<$post\n";
        my $wptr = $uptr;
        $wptr =~ s/G/_W/;
        my $wchartMangle = "$pre$wptr$post";
        $defline = "  $wchartMangle=$mangle  \@$ord";
        print "CHANGED: $defline\n";
        $usCount += 1;                 
      } else {
        # line doesn't contain unsigned short ptr
        $defline = "  $mangle  \@$ord";
      }
      push @expEntries, $defline;
    }
  }
  print "There are ".scalar(@expEntries)." export lines and $usCount of them contain an unsigned-short-pointer.\n";
  die "No entries found!" unless $usCount>0;
  print "Writing entries to $basename.def ...\n";
  foreach my $entry (@expEntries) {
    print $defh $entry."\n"; 
  }
  close($defh);

  my $cmdLib = "lib /DEF:$basename.def";
  print "Generate Export Lib from DEF-File: >> $cmdLib << ...\n";
  system($cmdLib); 
}
```